# CSS Horizontal menu bar displays correct in Internet Explorer, displays with no style in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, web, menubar

CSS Horizontal menu bar displays correct in Internet Explorer, displays with no style in Google Chrome..

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Chrome is just displaying a bullet list with the

tags as links.  No styling is being applied.

Comment: please try checking in incognito mode or refresh your page using ctrl+F5. There's nothing in your css which needs to be written for specific browser.

Comment: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/f580fnxy/

Comment: There is nothing needs to be modified for your code, 
its coming fine for me,created a fiddle here..just check

https://jsfiddle.net/satyaprasanna/29of4gze/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work you might have done some mistake with including the css files properly or you have to clear the cache ..using Ctrl+Shift+R or clear the browser cache from settings of google chrome(or do a hard Reload+ emptycache)

i'm adding the working code here. just try it

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a bug in Chrome where the CSS is not refreshing itself and use the CSS stored in cache. The way to correct that can be to open the source code on Google Chrome, click on your CSS file, refresh your CSS file with F5 and then refresh your normal page.

Answer (score 0):

How do you have your reference to styles?

If this is a folder in the same directory as your index.html file, then something like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
```

Make sure that your CSS and **HTM/HTML** files use the same encoding !

If your HTM/HTML files are encoded as **UNICODE**, your stylesheet has to be as well.

Clear cache as well and try.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix actually.  After viewing the style sheet Chrome was using, turn out it was not refreshing the style sheet.

Added:

to force browsers to use the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Internet Explorer **Compability view settings** Usually it will solve your problem.